# Can people with no physical senses from birth experience anything?

Tags: senses

In my world, some people are born with a condition called sensory blackout syndrome, in which they cannot see, hear, feel, smell, or taste. Is there a possible way for them to still have any experience? I don't mean that they can see, or hear, but I mean that they have some state of being. Is it possible for said people to have any experiences at all?

Comment: Seems like this is dependent on how you choose define the epistemology of your world. Until you define what is and isn't an experience you cannot answer whether someone could or couldn't experience something.

Comment: Humans are weird in that much of what we'd consider to be personality/intelligence/soul doesn't "boot up" except in certain conditions. While alot of our software is present from birth (before, really), that software isn't conscious at all. So if someone were surgically mutilated early on where their brain was alive, but disconnected from every sensory perception, you'd not get the Windows startup chime at all. Points: 1) I doubt this could happen via disease/birth-defect 2) "experience" is a subjective word and mostly meaningless and 3) enough variation exists there'd be exceptions.

Comment: What role does this condition play in your story? Is it a logical consequence of something else or do you hope to accomplish something by establishing it, and what?

Comment: Yes, we don't only have the senses we are used to, for example, this person would still sense if they were spun upside down due to the labyrinth in their ears that senses motion and isn't connected to any of the standard senses.

Comment: If this is something you want to include in your story and you intend for this story to be received by the general public I would highly recommend you find a sensitivity checker.

Comment: what about the other 6  or so senses, do they have them? I mean cutting off smell requires a completely different mechanism than the other senses. If they have no senses they have no experiences.

Comment: Very dark related story: https://www.creepypasta.com/gateway-of-the-mind/

Comment: So the 5 senses are not our only 5 senses.  They're the only senses of external conditions.  You have many more senses that are unrelated to the core 5 but are more based on your own internal sensory inputs, such as sense of balance, body position, hunger, thirst, a sense of suffocation, and a sense of nausea to name a few.  A person who is unable to detect outward stimuli may still be able to detect internal stimuli.

Comment: Do you have alternate ways to communicate with the baby in your world?  Telepathy?  Proprioception / the often-overlooked senses others have mentioned? Some sort of soul-to-soul link? Radio transceivers embedded right after birth?  If those sorts of things are in play, you might be able to develop a strange mind which relies on things other than the "standard" senses you've blocked.

Comment: Reminds me of this https://www.creepypasta.com/gateway-of-the-mind/

Comment: What is the technology level of your world? More advanced than present-day?

Answer (score 9):

Without checking up I don't know if this is a real syndrome or if it is that you accurately described it.

But .. With the symptoms you've described, namely that none of their senses work and that they experience no external stimuli of any sort, No, both by the literal definition and that of an internal existence within their own thoughts I presume you to mean, no, they can't experience anything.

Pain and any type of 'motion', 'impact' or 'gravity' sense we might have are propagated off of our sense of touch (mostly by nerves at the base of 'hairs' translating the motion of fluid in the inner ear for any motion related sense) so presumably none of them work either.

So (as you already stipulated anyway) no sensory input at all from birth, and likely before birth.

Which only leaves their own inner thoughts.

With no sensory input of any sort there can be no developmental progress of any sort either (let alone actual langauge acquisition) and without any of that there's no framework for any kind of internal monologue of any sort to exist within either.

No input from birth means no development and once each developmental window is passed it becomes impossible to make up that development later, this we know from various tragic real world examples.

> And if it really does have no working senses at all it's brain can't receive the necessery stimulus to instinctively start breathing after birth and it will simply asphyxiate and die unless put on a ventilator .. will have no swallow reflex so won't swallow when fed, etc.

So imagine a PC with no operating software, that's what you'll have, even if you can hook it up to some sensors later and switch it on that's all you'll have (and all you'll ever have), a blank screen that does nothing and never will.

> Hmm .. Musk's Neurolink does present us with a potential workaround for the lack of all sensory input if it was employed early enough, before all of the developmental windows have closed .. but I'm presuming that you're assuming no artificial intervention in all this?

Comment: What are you quoting?

Comment: ? Why doesn't internal reflection return anything?

Comment: @Joshua because the way our brains get 'programmed' is entirely through our senses, no senses no programming, you can't learn to crawl, walk, focus your eyes, recognise sounds, recognises faces, talk, and with no sensory input to provide anything to 'think about' a baby can't even learn to think .. in the situation described by OP of total sensory deprivation from birth (and most likely before) what you'll get is a lump of meet that does nothing and experiences nothing that never develops a working mind despite having a perfectly healthy physical brain.

Comment: @Joshua [continued] in summary no stimulus = nothing to stimulate any developmental connections in the brain and it will remain blank and once certain developmental periods are passed the plasticity that allows a baby, infant and child to learn as fast, as much & the way it does ends and many if not most if not all of those things they learn can then no longer be learned .. the brain just can't 'program' itself to think without **any** sensory stimuli and if it can't think then your 'internal reflection' just isn't possible is it 

Comment: @Pelinore: A well thought out response that didn't quite understand what internal reflection is. There are several extra "senses" simpler than normal sensory input and more likely to work even in total locked in syndrome. They are required for metabolic support including various blood management senses; that if they're not working ought to result in dead very quickly. Also, time of day rhythm sense is governed by a vision like thing that isn't wired into neurons normally. Reflection here results in being able to read these senses which are not immediately conscious unless mind asks for them.

Comment: @Joshua Ah, OK  most of these are I think autonomous stuff right? .. most of that doesn't generally get past the brain stem and some don't even bother to go even that near the brain .. and if it's not reaching the higher brain it's not going to be generating any connections that might plausibly develop some sort of self awareness or intelligence beyond an insects, if even that .. you need a **lot** of very varied input to develop a human brain into what we have as the smallest of toddlers let alone as adults, and those even if they did reach the higher brain, wouldn't plausibly be that.

Comment: @Joshua [continued] besides, I took him at his word in his title line and considered his list in the body text merely an incomplete list for the purpose of example for my answer, and assumed no working senses 

Answer (score 6):

This is a state that usually arises from brain damage and the medical term is [Persistent Vegetative State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_vegetative_state):

> The vegetative state is a chronic or long-term condition. This condition differs from a coma: a coma is a state that lacks both awareness and wakefulness. Patients in a vegetative state may have awoken from a coma, but still have not regained awareness. In the vegetative state patients can open their eyelids occasionally and demonstrate sleep-wake cycles, but completely lack cognitive function.

If the person has no senses at all, then they cannot react to stimuli, so they will not demonstrate any cognitive ability. Fits the description above.

Now if you google it a little  bit further, some articles mention that one in ten people in vegetative state may actually be conscious, but that was discovered by [scanning their brains and asking them to picture things](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg24232360-800-shocking-evidence-shows-people-in-vegetative-states-may-be-conscious/). A person who by design can never experience anything would neither hear the request nor picture anything, though, so whether they have a state of consciousness is up to philosophical debate.

---

But let's get creepy now. [Human <strike>brains in a jar</strike> neurons in a petri dish can learn to play Pong](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-022-03229-y). Those neurons don't have eyes nor ears connected to them, yet they are hard at work and making fast decisions based on what they've learned.

You could say that someone without senses can have a conscious experience, provided their brain is primed in a way similar to the petri dish neurons. That could be done by uploading stuff to that brain *a la* The Matrix.

Or we can jusy have a natural, hardwired consciousness - but given that we seem to have zero datapoints on this in the real world  this is again up to philosophical debate.

Comment: in the petridish they are being given senses via electrical connection.

Comment: @John which is why I suggest some priming - train a neural network, copy it, then cut the senses off.

Comment: +1 for philosophical debate point - the fact is there's no way of knowing how much of consciousness is "learned" and how much is "innate". This theoretical disorder would leave a person with only the "innate" part whatever that is.

Comment: The problem with those Petri dish neurons playing pong in relation to this question is that they **do** have (even if artificially supplied) sensory input  and the question is predicated on there being no sensory input.

Comment: @Pelinore my point is that you could train a neural network into a state, then copy that into a fresh new brain that is disconnected from any inputs. If that brain is then having thoughts of its own without having any inputs, you could philosophically debate whether it is conscious in spit of having no senses.

Answer (score 5):

**They're dead**

I don't know of a Real World example of what you're looking for. Good! I like new things. We do have something similar, it's called [congenital insensitivity to pain with anhidrosis (CIPA)](https://medlineplus.gov/genetics/condition/congenital-insensitivity-to-pain-with-anhidrosis/). In that case, the individual can't feel pain or temperature, but they can obviously see, hear, taste, smell, etc.

Go read that article about CIPA. It's important, because it's part of the basis for my answer. I see two basic physiological conditions that could rationalize your syndrome. The first (based on CIPA) is that the nervous system is inoperable. The brain literally receives no stimuli. *This is important!* Because, basically, the nerves in your nose and the nerves in your fingers are just that, *nerves.* It's the brain that makes the distinction between smell and touch.

If the nervous system is inoperable then the baby can't feel, taste, or smell the consumption of anything. The child might feel hunger, but won't feel/taste/smell available food. The [gag reflex won't work, either](https://www.healthline.com/health/dental-and-oral-health/gag-reflex), meaning the first time anyone tries to feed the baby it'll aspirate — if the baby chose to feed at all (there's nothing to tell the baby its mouth is open or closed...).

And that assumes that the nerves that control heart, lungs, kidneys, etc. function to allow the body to live at all.

So, what we know amongst humanity that behaves similarly to what you're looking for would result in death. Pretty quickly.

**Or... maybe they're not dead.**

But, let's assume the second physiological rationalization of the syndrome: *there's a problem with the brain.* Your autonomic functions (heart, lungs) work just fine, but the brain is unable to identify any other stimulus.

Humans have a few things like this, too. Consider [aphasia](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/5502-aphasia), where the brain can't get the body to speak or understand what other people are saying. Or things like [auditory processing disorder](https://www.healthyhearing.com/report/50491-Auditory-processing-disorders-in-children) where the ear works fine but the brain can't process the audio or [visual agnosia](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/23421-visual-agnosia) where the eyes work fine but the brain can't process the video. So, we have Real Life experience that supports your goal.

But, frankly, I think they're still dead. Even if we assume they can feel hunger and thirst, and the gag reflex works, the child can't tell if it's eating something that will kill it. It can't smell something that warns of danger. It can't feel pain. Lots of things go wrong when the body can't tell it's in danger.

But! Let's assume the parents know exactly what's going on and they selflessly sacrifice their own lives to ensure this child never stubs a toe or gets a cut (gangrene!), doesn't run into trees and avoids the oncoming honking cars. The parents quite literally become the child's guardian angels.  What then?

**You bet, if they live long enough to have an intellectual comprehension of what's happening around them, they'd experience plenty. Maybe...**

Vacating the senses doesn't vacate emotions. The first time our teenager gets cheated, the child will feel anger and hate. Love, jealousy, joy... all that could be experienced, just not in exactly the way the rest of us can. We might feel happy feeling a warm breeze on our faces. The child would feel happy that it's not hungry.

What constitutes "experience" would change quite a bit, but yes, it would happen.

But what's the point? The child has no way to learn association beyond the most basic things. It might get angry when it's hungry. It might actually feel serene when it's not. But since the child can't feel a pencil to be taught how to write (much less use Braille) and it can't even feel it's head being led to shake "no" or nod "yes," what's the value of any experience? There's no way for the child to know it has a world to interact with other than when it feels hungry something happens that makes the hunger go away. What's the point of experience if there's no way to act on it or share it?

So, I think I'd better stick with "they're dead."

*By the way, now that I've written my answer, I believe this to be another form of "how can I defeat my godlike character?" questions. The answer to all such questions is, "you can't, your godlike character needs a weakness." You're in the same boat. What experience the child could have would be so little and the results of that experience so irrelevant that the child might as well have no experience at all. Methinks you need to re-analyze why you want such an all-encompassing (aka, "godlike") ailment that you can basically do nothing with.*

Comment: We have pillow angels now. They're sad stories but not interesting characters. How much more are these not interesting characters. It's kind of like the one block of dirt skyblock. Why?

Answer (score 2):

**Everyone goes through sensory deprivation after birth, some don't regain their senses.**

The current scientific knowledge of how human brains develop after birth is not enough to answer this: it could be that they have some [innate model of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innatism), or they could be [a blank slate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa) until formed by external influences.

However, in an alternate world evolution could certainly drive development to the direction that there is pre-existing "experience" built into every brain. Consider some external condition that causes *temporary* sensory deprivation after birth. This could be e.g. cryo-sleep or long sheltering inside life support machinery. Any babies with inherent model of the world from birth would have a head start once released to the real world, so there would be natural selection pressure for this. It would take thousands or millions of years for evolutionary changes to occur.

Now, some children might never regain their senses, resulting in the syndrome you describe. They would know that there should be a world, and might even know enough to do basic bodily functions such as eating on schedule without feedback, but could never gain more information than they were born with.

Answer (score 2):

Despite elementary school teaching, you have more than five senses.

You have senses of balance, of temperature, of pain.

You have a sense of proprioception (close your eyes and touch your nose. What sense told you where your finger was before you touched it?)

You have a sense of your internal body, which is not the same as your sense of touch (feeling your heart beat, or your intestines move).

You have a sense of time.

So overall, yes. Your characters can still have many experiences.

(That's without going into neuroprostheses and similar).

Comment: Yes and that's irrelevant to the question .. I think the question is predicated on zero sensory input, yes it does provide an incomplete list of senses to demonstrate what it means but that's irrelevant to an answer, what you have here is a comment suitable for prompting improvement to the question with a more complete list of senses and as such it would be valid, but it's not a frame challenge or an answer  if I'm wrong about what the question is and it really was "what senses have I missed" then you'd be golden of course 

Answer (score 1):

It depends on two axes:

1. How much of a materialist you want to be. If your world allows for spiritual activity to directly affect the mind, then such a person would only be able to sense spiritual phenomena. If not, then we have no externally-caused experiences. If yes, then this would be quite interesting indeed. Such a person might be aware only of nothing except all the angels and devils which likely as not surround us constantly without our knowing, and yet would be unable to communicate this reality with anyone.
2. How much of our consciousness is innate and how much is learned. A person with your disorder would only have the innate part, and would think without language and only in terms of either pure imagination or instinctual knowledge. Thus, assuming there is an innate consciousness, they would experience their own thoughts, but they would only be able to think or reason based on pieces of innate knowledge (and possibly spiritual perception, see point 1).

   In the real world, it is impossible to say exactly what this entails; even from before birth, our consciousness is constantly being informed by sensory stimuli, so it's impossible to filter out what may be innate. Instinctual knowledge is a controversial subject, but it's unlikely that we're born completely blank slates. It seems like, in addition to desires necessary for survival like food and water, we have innate social and sexual desires. We seem to have an innate knowledge of what human faces look like. There even is some evidence that we have an innate knowledge that snakes and spiders are dangerous.

   If we assume that your disorder allows a person to perceive his/her own body, then they would experience hunger and thirst. It's likely also that they would experience loneliness.

Answer (score 1):

A person, although deprived of all sensory inputs, still has wants and needs based on their hardwired brain parts. Assuming those are still intact. For example: a person with zero input can still have a need to procreate. They still need shelter, or are perhaps, deprived of any sensory input, think that they are sheltered. And they probably still have some fear of the unknown.

However, [as some sources suggest,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feral_child) after a certain age, if their condition is not alleviated, it is likely that they will not be able to learn speech or form abstract thought.

Answer (score 0):

### Dreams and/or ESP

One theory on dreams is that they are caused by random electrical impulses that your brain interprets through its learned experiences.  Your child would have no learned experiences, but (provided you get around all of the physical reasons it would simply die) the brain does have electrical activity regardless.  I would think that it is possible that the brain's neural net would begin training itself.  We would have no idea of where that training would go.  It wouldn't be a "dream" as we know it, it would have no point of reference, but it may cause feedback that would develop neural pathways in certain ways.  It would be like the superstitious pigeons (https://awesci.com/superstitious-pigeons/); the brain may get *something* positive out of some electrical impulse that is generated by an outgoing impulse that moves an arm.  So the body flops an arm around every once in a while simply to activate a neuron.

The brain would be in a formative state, and would be training itself, but in a completely non-human way as far as we are concerned.  If there's any possibility of electrical activity being detected by our brain, whether there's ESP and ghost's in your world or just radio noise from the x-ray machine being turned on, this is when it would be picked up.  There's no external input to override whatever weak signal might be coming in, so the self-training neural net may amplify whatever it can get.  The chances of it ever doing anything with that are purely fantasy, though.  Maybe the brain ends up training itself to mimic the signal, so with ESP you get a thought coming out or an ekg reading that looks human, or maybe some electrical equipment starts acting up and it gets traced to some weird near-by feedback.

Answer (score 0):

## No, this person would not have any experiences

Some people believe the mind is a sense, but in truth it is the compiler of our senses; if it does not have any senses to receive input from, then the person is essentially dead. To change an analogy given in a previous answer, it would be like a PC with no keyboard or mouse, it might have some input already programmed into it, but it will never be able to do anything new.

Why couldn't they do other intellectual tasks? Well lets name a few:

- *Math*: How could you perform mathematical task if you have never seen the difference between two and three. They can't feel there fingers to count them either.
- *Music*: How would you know chords? What even is sound? You've never heard it.
- *Stories*: You've never seen, smelt, tasted, or felt anything. You would have no where to begin in constructing a story.
- *Memory*: There is nothing to remember. If you were dropped from a two story building you wouldn't even know it.
- *Dreaming*: Even the wildest of dreams still have people, places, and things. This person would have never seen any of those and therefore the only thing they might dream about is the same blackness they are used to.

My point isn't to give an exhaustive list but hopefully you see my point that there would be nothing for them to experience without senses.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a thing, rather than a person. The world telephone network may have as many circuits as the human brain, and the same mixture of long and short range connections. It is complex enough to think. The individual phone messages might double as neutrons firing to it. But what would it think about? Would it be like the creature in the abyss of no dimensions in 'Flatland', who knows no other world but itself.

Ray Bradbury put it like this...

Night Call, Collect.

```
Suppose and then suppose and then suppose
That wires on the far-slung telephone black poles

Sopped up the billion-flooded words they heard
Each night all night and saved the sense
And meaning of it all.

Then, jigsaw in the night,
Put all together and
In philosophic phase
Tried words like moron child.

Thus mindless beast
All treasuring of vowels and consonants
Saves up a miracle of bad advice
And lets it filter whisper, heartbeat out
One lisping murmur at a time.

So one night soon someone sits up
Hears sharp bell ring, lifts phone
And hears a voice like Holy Ghost
Gone far in nebulae
That beast upon the wire,
Which with sibilance and savorings
Down continental madnesses of time
Says Hell and O
And then Hell-o.

To such Creation
Such dumb brute lost Electric Beast,
What is your wise reply?
```